# Gigabyte H410M graphics card support

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard, gaming

Can Gigabyte H410M support graphics cards such as RTX 3080? What are some of the latest graphics cards that H410M can support?

Answer (score 1):

In theory it can support the 3080 just fine, it has a PCI-e16x3.0 connection so I see no reason why it wouldn't.